# Xamarin.forms sqlite-net lookup an Id

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, sqlite-net

Thanks in advance,

I am using SQLite-net Frank Krueger and the code written by James Montemagno as per this video: [Motz Code Live Sqlite](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_MX5ZrDAXP8&t=2822s)   and GitHub:  [2015-08-21 SQLite-net PCL](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MotzCodesLive/tree/master/2015-08-21%20SQLite-net%20PCL)

I have it all working, but want to know how I can look up the Id field that is included in the BusinessEntityBase.cs

```
public class BusinessEntityBase : IBusinessEntity
{
    public BusinessEntityBase()
    {
    }

    #region IBusinessEntity implementation
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id
    {
        get; set;
    }
    #endregion
```

I have a table that uses this BusinessEntityBase and therefore the Id field:

```
public class ActivityItemDB : BusinessEntityBase


{

    public string ActivityNameDB { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string ActivityCategoryDB { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string ActivityImageDB { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string ActivitySelectedDB { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public int ActivityAbilityDB { get; set; } = 0;

}
```

I have a page, where I wish to update a record in that table.  I know the value of the ActivityNameDB (which is unique), I wish to use this to look up the value of the Id field, so that I can then update the correct record.

How do I do get this Id value?

Or should I have carried the Id value through to this page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just carry the value between the 2 pages.

Otherwise you'll have to do a call to the database to get the id out which is a lot of extra work for no reason.

Comment: Thanks.  I think I just needed to be told that.  :)

Comment: It's always better to pass 1 value than to look that one value backup, good luck, and if you find this answer good enough don't forget to mark it ;)

Comment: Thanks. That is what I have now done and all working.